# How can I generate X Axis componant in R_xy in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, cross-correlation, correlation

Let's say I have cross-correlated $x(n)$ and $y(n)$ and got the $R_{xy}(n)$.

Now if I want to **generate the x-axis component of $R_{xy}(n)$ in the command window** of MATLAB. How can I do that? is there any built-in function available?

Comment: `xaxis = -(length(x)-1):(length(y)-1);` multiply with whatever units your actual signals are in

Comment: @Hilmar may as well add that as an answer since there isn't much more to say about it- and close this out.

Comment: @Hilmar How can I generate the Y-axis component?